# Regular expression match numbers

Tags: regex

My regular expression knowledge is poor however I have worked out what the following expression does but not sure how to modify it.

this is the expression `^[0-9]{6,15}$`

which matches 6 numbers and make sure there is nothing else at the end of the string for example it matches 123456

However I need it to match 123456 and 123456-1

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: What are the criteria? Now, even `^[0-9-]{6,15}$` will do.

Comment: It is very likely that what the OP is trying to do (beyond the vague criteria given in the question for an updated regex expression) is modify some more fundamental aspect of some existing data model (like changing some unit or widget or record id to allow for "-xxx" type suffixing.) I know we can't save every line of code at every level, but when the question is poorly written and doesn't meet minimum standards _and_ it's fairly clear that the intention is to paste any solution we guess might help into existing code,  lets **vote to close**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down: `^[0-9]{6,15}$`

- `^` : beginning of line
- `[0-9]` : a character class representing any
  character in the range 0-9.
- `{6,15}` : match between 6 and 15
  (inclusive I think) occurrences of whatever the previous thing is (in
  this case it was a character class).
- `$` : end of line

We want to add optional matching for something like `-[0-9]`. We can add an optional match using `?`.

All together now:

`^[0-9]{6,15}(-[0-9])?$`

The `(-[0-9])?` means "optionally match a dash followed by a single digit".

Comment: I think you might be misusing the word pedantic, but I up-voted you anyway.  Your answer clearly covers what needs covering for the OP at the level of their question, which is : "here's what your current regex is actually doing", enabling them to grow from there.